# What happens when you delete the Windows 10 update file and try to reset the PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I have deleted my old Windows backup file and also the Windows update file via clean up disk option. So now if I choose to reset this PC, will my PC be restored to Windows 10?

(Reverting back to Windows 7 will not work as I have deleted the old Windows installation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the factory reset would go back to the original out of box state.

You need to get Windows 10 install media and use that to re-install Windows 10.
If you don't have it already use the [Media Creation tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10).

You don't need a key as your device already has a Windows 10 digital license. If asked for a key select Skip, Do this later or I do not have a key.

See this article :
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 10 via media creation tool and some online sites suggested that Windows 10 will be reinstalled (I hade to reset cause I changed something in the registry to solve context menu handler) and as soon as I restarted the PC it got stuck in a automatic restart loop.

Comment: Lots of information exists on how to get out of it, for example : [article1](https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-reboot-loop-after-windows-10-update.html) and [article2](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-stuck-in-endless-reboot-loop). If you manage to boot into Safe mode, backup first your data before doing any more manipulations.

Comment: Right now it's in the Windows reinstall screen and the UI looks like that of Windows 10 so will this solve my problem cause I have decided to keep my files and remove apps and settings that didn't came with the laptop (In the Reset PC Menu)!